# Time Complexity of an Algorithm (Nested Loops)

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm trying to figure out the time complexity of this pseudocode given algorithm:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= n / 6; j++)
        sum = sum + 1;
```

I know that the first line runs

**n times**

But I'm not sure about the second line.

Comment: time complexity = sum ? :)  (n*n/6)

Comment: Wouldn't that just be O(n^2)? Seems to simple.

Comment: It doesn't always have to be hard :)

Comment: Okay, if I understand this correctly, if the second loop were to be j=1 to n/i, would the resulting complexity be (n*n/i) which is again O(n^2)?

Comment: Yes @Aede, did you check the answers, they explain it. :)

Comment: Yep I'm good, thanks

Comment: Oh OK my bad, forgot that! Good question btw, so I will upvote since it's your first time, but please make sure that you post the appropriate questions in the appropriate sites of Stack Exchange next time. :)

Comment: Actually, @Aede, if the second loop was from 1 to n/i, you would be making n+n/2+n/3+...+n/n operations, and the time complexity would be n*log(n) - see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%28sum+from+i%3D1+to+i%3Dn+of+n%2Fi%29%2F%28n*log+n%29+as+n+goes+to+infinite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a simple double loop:

```
for i=1;i<=n;i++
   for j=1; j<=n/6; j++
```

so if you count how many times the body of the loop will be executed (i.e. how many times this line of code `sum = sum + 1;` will be executed), you will see it's:

> n*n/6 = n²/6

which in terms of big-O notation is:

> O(n²)

because we do not really care for the constant term, because as `n` grows, the constant term makes no (big) difference if it's there or not!

---

When and *only when* you fully realize what I am saying, you can go deeper with this nice question: [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

---

However, please notice that such questions are more appropriate for the [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), rather than SO.

Answer (score 4):

Using Sigma notation, we can find the asymptotic bounds of your algorithm as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You make n*n/6 operations, thus, the time complexity is O(n^2/6) = O(n^2).

Comment: More precisely, `n * (n / 6)` operations: the complexity is the same, but the result differs.